# Unable to deploy the index and grammar file in KES

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using [Knowledge Exploration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/kes/overview) by Azure. I've prepared a grammar and an index file. Since, the size of it was small I was able to run it on my local machine and on a Azure VM.

But now, I want to deploy this service. Issue is when I run the command `kes deploy_service` it is unable to download the blob from Azure Storage. Even when I try to provide the file from my local machine.

Followed the same steps on a Azure VM and I receive the same errors.

```
>kes deploy_service Some.grammar Some.index kes-example
00:00:00 Index: Some.index
00:00:00 ERROR: Invalid value for index parameter: 'Some.index' is not a blob URI.

>kes deploy_service Some.grammar https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/Some.index kes-example
00:00:00 Index: https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/Bell.index
00:00:02 ERROR: ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'storagename' was not found.
```

The container has public access. I can download the file via the browser and even via Azure CLI.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** Adding a sample index file which I've uploaded on Azure Storage with public access. This index file was generated using the Academic example in the documentation.

```
>kes describe_index https://kesstorage.blob.core.windows.net/kess/Academic.index
ERROR: ResourceNotFound: The storage account 'kesstorage' was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kes.exe is using the old Service Management API.  It is querying the API for Storage Accounts in your subscription, but this API predates Azure Resource Manager (ARM), and therefore has no knowledge of ARM Storage Accounts.  You will need to use a Classic Storage Account instead.

For how to create a Classic storage account tutorial, refer to this link: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account#create-a-storage-account**

Comment: I even ran a `describe_index` with the URL and I am still receving the same error. Check the edit in my question.

Comment: If I provide the same index file locally, I get the desired output with `describe_index`.

Comment: not sure if it matters, in the example they used http rather than https for the blob URL: 
kes.exe deploy_service http://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/Academic.grammar  
Can you retry it using similar syntax ?
Source:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/kes/gettingstarted#testing-service

Comment: I reached out to the author to see if they could help. I'll get back to you as soon as I get an update.

Comment: I added a section for the Publish settings file, could you ensure if it was saved ?
Also, is you VM using Classic or ARM on your VM ?

Comment: Yes, the Publish Settings file is already present. Generated it based on the single subscription that I have - Free Trial. The VM I'm using is Standard A1 (1 vcpu, 1.75 GB memory).

Comment: Could you confirm if it was deployed under classic or ARM when you initially created the VM ?

Comment: How do I check if it's under classic or ARM?

Comment: When you open the virtual machine blade in azure portal, you should be able to see the type of deployments, if it only says "virtual machine" it means that it's ARM, if it says classic under the vm name, then it's classic :)

Comment: It's says "Virtual Machine". So, it's ARM according to your analogy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168242/discussion-between-jroddynamite-and-adam-smith-msft).

Comment: I just updated the answer based on the support ticket. This would be helpful for the community as a future reference should they run into the same issue :)